# What's that process called where you form new group law by $x \star y = x \cdot a \cdot y$ for some $a$ in the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group.  We can form new groups $(A, \cdot a \cdot)$ where $a$ is any element of $A$.  Choosing $a = 1$ the identity of $A$ gives $A$ itself.

Clearly, associativity comes from associativity and commutativity of $A$.

Identity is $x \cdot a \cdot e = x$ or $e = a^{-1}$.

Inverse is $x \cdot a \cdot y = a^{-1}$ or $y = a^{-1} x^{-1} a^{-1}$.

What is this group formation process called and do the groups relate back to $A$?

I've seen it somewhere, and can't find where again.

Comment: $A$ doesn't have to be Abelian. This whole game has something to do with *torsors*.

Comment: There is an isomorphism $(A,\cdot)\to(A, \cdot a\cdot)$ given by $x\mapsto xa^{-1}$. For groups like vector spaces, this is known as "moving the origin to $a$".

Comment: Also known as [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Comment: For a recent paper see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03139.pdf), with $X\star Y:=XAY$, where it is called "sandwich".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this also for groups, but it seems to be more interesting for Lie algebras, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207459/earliest-source-for-a-lie-algebra-construction) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140554/homotopes-of-simple-lie-algebras). For groups it seems to be called *variant*, see the comments at the above questions, or a *sandwich*, e.g., Semigroups under a sandwich operation, Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc. (Ser. 2) 26 (1983), 371-382.

For $K$-algebras $(A,\cdot)$ with multiplication $x\cdot y$ a new multiplication
$x\circ_z y$ depending on a fixed $z$ is called a *homotope*, or a *mutation*.